# Read .txt file in python, assign first line to a variable and from 2nd line to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, text-files, read-csv

Working on Python script to read .txt files(space seperated) to a pandas dataframe. But 1st line contain server information. How do I extract 1st line to other variable and remaining file content to a pandas dataframe?

Sample file1.txt

**srv123  12_45/56-01V top**
Date location character1 character2 character3
2023-01-24 asd 3434.56 67.567 898.898
2023-01-24 axs 345.56 78.567 934.898
2023-01-24 ert 4567.56 89.123 901.898
2023-01-25 tgb 7879.56 90.567 456.898

Expected Dataframe :

| server | Date | location | character1 | character2 | character3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| srv123 | 2023-01-24 | asd | 3434.56 | 67.567 | 898.898 |
| srv123 | 2023-01-24 | axs | 345.56 | 78.567 | 934.898 |
| srv123 | 2023-01-24 | ert | 4567.56 | 89.123 | 901.898 |
| srv123 | 2023-01-25 | tgb | 7879.56 | 90.567 | 456.898 |

I tried with read_csv but first line and header are messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the first line with `next`, then pass the rest of the file to `read_csv`:

```
with open('Sample file1.txt') as f:
    my_var = next(f)
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=' +')
```

Output:

```
# my_var
srv123 12_45/56-01V top

# df
         Date location  character1  character2  character3
0  2023-01-24      asd     3434.56      67.567     898.898
1  2023-01-24      axs      345.56      78.567     934.898
2  2023-01-24      ert     4567.56      89.123     901.898
3  2023-01-25      tgb     7879.56      90.567     456.898
```

Comment: @Kavyashree I'm surprised you say that it's perfect when the dataframe is not as you require it to be. Specifically, it's missing the *server* column

Comment: I can get server name from variable my_var and add new column to dataframe.  This solved 99% of the requirement

Comment: @Kavyashree what is the missing 1%?

Comment: server = my_var.split('\t')[0]     df[server] = server    so this will add column server to the df

Answer (score 0):

The [skiprows](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#:%7E:text=skiprowslist%2Dlike%2C%20int%20or%20callable%2C%20optional) parameter in the read_csv call, when set to 1, will skip the first row of your file. This should skip the line you want to avoid adding to the dataframe.

Comment: This however requires you to read the file twice.

Comment: How would you do this and also get the **server** column? That can only be deduced from the first line in the file

Comment: skiprows are deleting header, where has next() is working fine

Comment: I can add another column to dataframe and fill all rows with the my_var